# Asynchronous API - POST & GET - multiple GET endpoints

Tags: rest, asynchronous, http-status-codes, restful-url, asyncapi

I am building an Asynchronous API with polling and it has the following endpoints -

1. POST Create Resource

```
Request - 

curl -X POST https://api.example.com/v1/card/eligibility/

Response - 
{
  "requestId": "12345678",
  "timestamp": "2021-11-01",
  ...
}
```

2. GET Fetch Resource - we can use it for polling top

```
Request - 
curl -X GET https://api.example.com/v1/card/eligibility/12345678

Response - 
{
   eligibilityStatus: Eligible/Ineligible 
   orderData: abc
   ..
}
```

Can I expose a separate GET endpoint working on the same requestId to run a function over the same resource?

3rd endpoint

```
Request - 
curl -X GET https://api.example.com/v1/card/product-eligibility/12345678

Response - 
{
   product-eligibility: 111
   orderData: abc
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), you will first have to model your domain.

For a REST API, your paths should reflect the *models* in your domain. If you have a "card" model, then you expose the operations on this model at a `/card` endpoint, which you already have.

There is not a lot of information about your domain in your question, but I will try to answer with some assumptions.

A card might have an eligibility, and eligible products that can be bought with it, which should be reflected in the responses to GET `/card`

So you would POST `/card` and receive a response reflecting the model that you just created:

```json
{
    "id": "12345678",
    "createdOn": "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
    "eligible": true,
    "eligibleProducts": [
        111
    ]
}
```

You now have an ID that you can query at `/card/:id`.

For example GET `/card/12345678`, which will give you the model response:

```json
{
    "id": "12345678",
    "createdOn": "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
    "eligible": true,
    "eligibleProducts": [
        111
    ]
}
```

For the concept of "product eligibility" or "order" and how these tie into your "card" model and what the relationships between these models are, there is simply not enough information about your domain in your question to give an appropriate answer.